# How can I flash my laptop's BIOS with Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, flash, bios

I'm running Ubuntu 15.04 on a HP Elitebook 6930p. I want to downgrade the BIOS by flashing a `ROM.bin` file. I already found the desired `ROM.bin` file from the HP website, I'm just having trouble flashing it.

I tried to flash my bios using [Flashrom](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Flashing_BIOS_from_Linux#Flashrom), but this didn't work:

```
$ sudo flashrom --programmer internal              
[sudo] password for user: 
flashrom v0.9.7-r1852 on Linux 3.19.0-28-generic (x86_64)
flashrom is free software, get the source code at http://www.flashrom.org

Calibrating delay loop... OK.
========================================================================
WARNING! You seem to be running flashrom on an unsupported laptop.
Laptops, notebooks and netbooks are difficult to support and we
recommend to use the vendor flashing utility. The embedded controller
(EC) in these machines often interacts badly with flashing.
See the manpage and http://www.flashrom.org/Laptops for details.

If flash is shared with the EC, erase is guaranteed to brick your laptop
and write may brick your laptop.
Read and probe may irritate your EC and cause fan failure, backlight
failure and sudden poweroff.
You have been warned.
========================================================================
Aborting.
Error: Programmer initialization failed.
```

So how can I flash my laptop's BIOS with Ubuntu?

Comment: See [my answer for Asus](http://askubuntu.com/a/338777/3940). Hp and many other vendors also offer a bootable FreeDOS for BIOS upgrade on their BIOS download page