# Dell Optiplex 980 bios update

Tags: bios

I want to update BIOS on my Dell Optiplex 980 as it's never been updated.

I checked Dell site and they state that Ubuntu 9.10 os is supported. I have Kubuntu 17.10 on mine. Wondering if this will work: http://www.dell.com/support/home/ie/en/iebsdt1/product-support/product/optiplex-980/drivers

Also, how woul I do this when I d/l from Dell site

Thanks

Comment: See e.g. https://askubuntu.com/a/338777/3940 - if you do not need a BIOS update for a certain additional feature **you know** it offers (e.g. newer CPU support) I'd not do it.

Comment: Thanks. That was my thinking too; if it works, don't fix it!  I was concerned though about the recent security scare affecting Intel CPUs

Comment: I'm not so much of a hardware guy but AFAIK it was solved from software, i.e. the Ubuntu kernel. A BIOS update will not help then.