# Update bios in ubuntu using exe file?

Tags: uefi, 15.10, bios

Recently I've decided to remove windows completely and just use linux. For the past couple of months I've noticed the entire system freezing completely and my laptops fans start to spin really loud, I assume this is because of a kernel panic because it doesnt just happen with ubuntu it also happens on LM, arch, any distro really.

I checked acer's website and my bios version is 2.11 but the latest is 2.14 which includes some updated micro code for intel or something ? So I think updating the bios might help the only issue is I don't use windows and dont want to install it on my pc ...

I've tried booting into the windows 8 install disc that came with my pc but i cant find my usb drive inside cmd( I thought it would be best to just run cmd and open the exe file for updating the BIOS that way.)

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are u looking to update youe kernel?  'sudo apt-get dist-upgrade'  ?

Comment: You will have to create some sort of DOS boot.  Best is to search for DOS boot disks, and create one with your EXE file on it to load.  Look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/176141/how-to-create-dos-boot-usb-flash-drive-with-xubuntu) for creating one.

Comment: No I'm not updating the kernel I'm updating my BIOS but the bios update file I need to run is an EXE file, but I don't have windows to run it. Thanks @Terrance I'll try that and see how it goes .. i could use something like win32diskimager?

Comment: I haven't messed around with something like that one yet.  I do know, that if you create a DOS boot USB, you should be able to copy the EXE directly to the USB then run it from there.

Comment: BTW, I did update my comment with a link to UNetBootin to create the DOS boot USB drive.

Comment: Yeah I got unetbootin and selected freeDOS and selected the exe as the image and wrote it ... or are you saying to just write the freeDOS with no file selected and then move the exe after that ?

Comment: Yes, copy the EXE after the USB is created with FreeDOS.  No file needs to be selected to create the USB.  FreeDOS is built in.

Comment: hmm I get this error when trying to move the file on to the usb. There was an error copying the file into /media/travis/d77b5385-3fde-40a7-9488-52068bcb4efb. also should I be using a certain format on the USB?

Comment: It should be formatted to FAT32

Comment: Also see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/144526/how-to-flash-a-bios-when-only-a-windows-binary-is-provided and http://askubuntu.com/a/338777/3940

Comment: @Terrance make it an answer :-)

Comment: @Rinzwind I would, but too bad it was already an answer.  :(  =)